# Openvpn gateway, redirect only remote local traffic

Tags: networking, raspberry-pi3, openvpn

I currently have an OpenVPN server (install on Raspbian, in gateway mode), which, when connecting, passes all Internet traffic through it. I want only the resource requests contained on the remote local network to be shared.

This would give:

```
User --> request to Remote File Server --> VPN (10.0. *. *)
User --> other request                 --> Local gateway
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I have a similar problem, I think: I have an OpenVPN server in Cloud and a client on a Debian system. I connect the client to the VPN using a configuration file called `debian.ovpn`.
I want the following to happen:
a) route all traffic to/from the VPN network (`10.8.0.*`) through the VPN itself;
b) route all remaining traffic through local gateway.
have you got any new insight on how this may be obtained?

Answer (score 0):

This is something you can change in your client (.ovpn) configuration. If you export your user profile to an ovpn file:

`ovpn_getclient username > username.ovpn`

Edit this username.ovpn file and comment out this section:

`redirect-gateway def1` -> `#redirect-gateway def1`

Comment: I don't see this line in my client.ovpn, I tried to change the route, it works, but I have a problem with the dns, indeed if I ping google via the raspberry it works, but when I am on a remote pc with raspberry as a gateway, it does not work not, yet I can ping all hardware on the server network, as well as external ip's such as 8.8.8.8. But impossible to ping a domain name

Comment: It could be helpful to share more information, such as your openvpn.conf file and parts of the ovpn file. Regarding the DNS issue, it is most likely in your openvpn.conf file where you can push the dns-option as such: `push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"`

Comment: I have a similar problem; my `.ovpn` file is something like this:

`
client
dev tun
proto udp
sndbuf 0
rcvbuf 0
remote DOMAIN 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
remote-cert-tls server
auth SHA512
cipher AES-256-CBC
setenv opt block-outside-dns
key-direction 1
verb 3
`

Answer (score 0):

Change device mode to "tap - Layer 2 mode" in server settings, This will connect the client part of the remote network but internet traffic will pass through the local gateway. to pass through the traffic for the selected client add "route-delay 15" in the server config. and add "push “route-delay 15” " in the client advanced config section.